# Using Tkinter with a SQL Query - How to reference row/column values later on

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I'm new to Python and trying to figure out if I'm going about this the wrong way.

I want to execute a SQL query against a database and display the results in a table with editable fields.  The number of rows and columns aren't fixed and is defined by the results of the SQL query.  Once the editable fields are updated, I want to take the updated values and generate an update statement by clicking on the button associated with the row I want to update.  Right now, the button calls a function and passes the row number that I want to update.

I have the query part working and the values are shown in a tkinter table which is built by iterating through the cursor, specify the row and column values and using .insert .  What I cannot figure out is how to reference the current values for each cell in that row when the button is clicked.

Is it possible to reference specific row/column values later on or am I going about this the wrong way?

I build the table using the code below:

```
    for rowcolumn in cur:
    updatebtn[i] = tk.Button(root, bg="gray", text="Update Record" , command=lambda i=i:update_row(i+1))
    updatebtn[i].grid(column=0, row=i+2, sticky="nsew")
    for j in range(len(rowcolumn)):
        noofcols = int(len(rowcolumn))
        tabledata = Entry(root,  fg='blue', borderwidth=2, relief='ridge')
        tabledata.grid(row=i+2, column=j+1)
        if rowcolumn[j] is not None:
            tabledata.insert(END, rowcolumn[j])
        else:
            tabledata.insert(END, "None")
```

So is there something like .get(row, col)?

Comment: Use a 2D list to store the table of entries.

Comment: A 2D list would only store the values returned from the initial SQL.  I need the latest values from the table to retain any entries updated by the user.

Comment: I mean a 2D list to store the `Entry` widgets.